# Extract a value between semicolons that has a word you want in regex

Tags: regex

How can I use regex to pull a the following column titles out of a header list?

**Case 1 -** `;CASE_NUMBER;CASE_STATUS;CASE_SUBMITTED;...` -> CASE_STATUS

**Case 2 -** `;LCA_CASE_NUMBER;STATUS;LCA_CASE_SUBMIT;...` -> STATUS

Here is what I've tried:

1. (?<=;)STATUS;

Positive Lookbehind (?<=;)
Assert that the Regex below matches
; matches the character ; literally (case sensitive)
STATUS; matches the characters STATUS; literally (case sensitive)

2. (?<=;).*STATUS;

I added to include characters in between the ; and the word STATUS. I realize the current notation is "greedy", so I finally tried the next option.

3. (?<=;).*?STATUS;

This is supposed be "lazy", meaning it should only grab everything after the first ; it encounters before STATUS. However, I am getting the same results when using 2 and 3 as a regex and both capture the words starting at the initial semi colon.

How do I extract the letters from the first semicolon behind STATUS to the first semi colon after STATUS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However lazy the `.*?` pattern is, the `.` can match any char (usually all but line break chars) including `;` if the patterns after `.*?` can appear *after* a `;`.

You may use

```
[^;]*STATUS[^;]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fuv57V/1)

**Details**

- `[^;]*` - 0+ chars other than `;`
- `STATUS` - your word
- `[^;]*` - 0+ chars other than `;`.